# Where am i wrong in drupal 7 php if else statement?

Tags: php, drupal, if-statement, drupal-7, field

I'm using **Drupal 7** + **Ubercart 3,6**.
Some products in store are not for sale, because of this, i've inserted a checkbox, so planing to display sell price, quantity and add to cart, when checkbox is checked (e.g. equals 1).

When checkbox is not checked (equals 0), it will be printed: **make enquiry link**.

```
<?php
  if ($content['field_for_sale']==1)
  {
    print $nid = $node->nid;
    print $nid;
    uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);
  }
  else
  {
    "<a class='colorbox-node' href='http://localhost/drupalgeya99/make_enquirywidth=600&height=600'>Make Enquiry2:</a>";  
  }
?>
```

It doesn't display any errors, but also doesn't print the if and else statement.
Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to print `$nid` varibale twice, and also you missed a `print` in `else`:

```
<?php 
if ($content['field_for_sale']==1) {
    $nid = $node->nid; 
    print $nid;
    uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);
} else {
    print "<a class='colorbox-node' href='http://localhost/drupalgeya99/make_enquirywidth=600&height=600'>Make Enquiry2:</a>";
}
?>
```

And I don't know your goals, but maybe you meant also to print **uc_currency_format** like: `print uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Victor Yes, i want to display it also, but now it display me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: field_for_sale in include() (line 14 of 
>   C:\Xampp\htdocs\drupalgeya99\themes\corporateclean\node-
>   product.tpl.php).

Also it always displaying me the link for "make enquery" (equals 0).

I`m using custom product node template for ubercart product page **node-product.tpl.php**.

This is my code for template:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="titleprod"><h1><?php print $title ?></h1></div>
<div class="prodwrap">
<div class="prodpage">
<?php print render($content['uc_product_image']['0']);?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="prodlist"><ul>
<li><h3><a href="#Product_description">Product description</a></h3></li>
<li><h3><a href="#field_technical">Technical specification</a></h3></li>
<li><h3><a href="#field_accessoaries">Accessoaries and spare parts</a></h3></li>
<li><h3><a href="#field_broshure">Broshure</a></h3></li>
<li><h3><?php 
if ($content['field_for_sale']==1) {
    $nid = $node->nid; print $nid; 
    print uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);
} else {
    print "<a class='colorbox-node' href='http://localhost/drupalgeya99/make_enquiry?width=600&height=600'>Make Enquiry:</a>";
}
?></h3></li>
<li><h3>More information:</h3></li>
<li><?php print render($content['field_logo_list']);?></li>
</ul></div>
<br>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br>
<div class="text-align"><a name="Product_description"></a><?php print render($content['body']);?> </div>
<br>
<div class="text-align"><a name="field_technical"></a><?php print render($content['field_technical_specification']);?> </div>
<br>
<div class="text-align"><a name="field_table"></a><?php print render($content['field_table']);?> </div>
<br>
<div class="text-align"><a name="field_accessoaries"></a> <?php print render($content['field_accessoaries_and_spare_par']);?> </div>
<br>
<div class="text-align"><a name="field_broshure"></a> <?php print render($content['field_broshure']);?> </div>
```

My boolean field settings page:
[This is my 1st image](http://s12.postimg.org/f3e1vuex9/for_sale_1.png)
[This is second from same page](http://s8.postimg.org/g96pd5spx/for_sale_2.png)

I think that my wrong is in boolean field settings page, missing something, but i don`t know what.

Comment: please install devel module and enable it. After that you can use the dpm() function to check what variables are available. For example try dpm($content); and dpm($node); It seems like your $content variable doesn't have the information that you assume it has.

Comment: maybe the value you are looking for is in `$node->field_for_sale['und'][0]['value']` which can also be accessed as `$node->field_for_sale[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`